# AngularJS ng-style tied to persistent variable and CSS transitions

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions

**Simple version**
I have a variable in ng-style that sets the CSS `left` property. Since the element has a transition, any movement is noticeable. I want it to go from e.g., 400 to 500, but it always starts from 0, giving a "jump" effect. Is this a problem with the way Angular's binding works?

**Detailed version**
I have an HTML element that needs the CSS `left` property is calculated off the route. When the route changes the element slides over to another position. My problem is the element is restting to position 0 and then animating from here to the correct position, when it should be animating from the current position.

```
<div id="deviceCursor" ng-style="myService.getCursorPosition"></div>

#deviceCursor {
        position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0;
        @include transition(all, 750ms, cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000));
    }
```

I've tried storing the left position variable in both the current controller and a service, but with both, the element resets to 0 before animating to the correct position. I have console.log's in my controller, and they do *not* sure the variable being reset to 0. If I paste in a left value directly into a live web inspector, the transition goes directly to the position intended, without resetting to 0, so I know the CSS is correct.

This would be easy with jQuery, but is there a correct AngularJS way?

**Service**

```
var nav = {

        cursorPosition: 0,

        calculateCursorPosition: function(devicePosition){

            var width = 276;
            var delta = 39;

            return ((devicePosition * width) - delta);  
        }
    };

    // Public API
return {

  moveCursorToDevice: function(devicePosition){
    nav.cursorPosition = nav.calculateCursorPosition(devicePosition);
  },

  getCursorPosition: function(){
    console.log("Pos: " + nav.cursorPosition);          
    return {left: (nav.cursorPosition + "px")};
  }

};
```

Comment: You might want to simplify your question to attract some helpful answers.